# How to fetch someone's profile info using LinkedIn APIs

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Is LinkedIn exposes APIs to fetch someone's profile info from LinkedIn using email or name?

Answer (score 0):

[You will have to be logged in to view this, but here is the People Search API link](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/people/people-search-api)

Comment: I tried using people search API but it gives error that access to people search denied

Comment: Probably due to when they locked down their APIs. I woudl try this https://apigee.com/console/linkedin and see what you get.